# CocoaPods Header Search

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm experiencing what would seem a very basic problem and that is header files not being found. Below is a basic directory structure for a test POD I've created, my requirement is to retain the directory structure and for both root and SubPods to have access to header files. To retain the directory structure I'm using SubPods, if none of the classes make any reference to other classes the POD validates and the structure is correct. But if TSTSubClasses1.h includes TSTRootClass.h the POD lint validation fails 'fatal error: 'TSTRootClass.h' file not found.

```
Classes/TSTRootClass.h
Classes/TSTRootClass.m
Classes/SubPod-1/TSTSubClass1.h
Classes/SubPod-1/TSTSubClass1.m
Classes/SubPod-2/TSTSubClass2.h   
Classes/SubPod-2/TSTSubClass2.m
```

I've tried various combinations of public_header_files, preserve_paths & s.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '${PODS_ROOT}/**'} but no luck. Is there any where that explains how to resolve search issues, also is there any way of outputting PATH details?

Detailed below is the podspec file, the source has been pushed to the repo and the structure and files do exist.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name                       = "PODTest"
  s.version                    = "0.1.0"
  s.summary                    = "PODTest dg dghjghj fghj ."
  s.description                = <<-DESC
                               sdfg sdfg adfg sdfgn of PODTest
                               DESC
  s.homepage                   = "http://myhomepage"
  s.license                    = 'MIT'
  s.author                     = { "Duncan Hill" => "myemail@somedomain.com" }
  #s.source                    = { :git => "git@bitbucket.org:reponame/podtest.git"}
  s.source                     = { :git => "git@bitbucket.org:reponame/podtest.git", :tag     => s.version.to_s }

  s.platform                   = :ios, '5.0'
  s.ios.deployment_target      = '5.0'
  s.requires_arc               = true
  #s.xcconfig                  = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '${PODS_ROOT}/#{s.name}/**'}
  s.xcconfig                   = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '${PODS_ROOT}/**'}

  s.source_files               = "Classes/*.{h,m}"
  s.preserve_paths             = "Classes/*"

  s.subspec "SubPod-1" do |ss|
    ss.public_header_files = "Classes/*.h"
    ss.source_files        = "Classes/SubPod-1/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "SubPod-2" do |ss|
    ss.public_header_files = "Classes/*.h"
    ss.source_files        = "Classes/SubPod-2/*.{h,m}"
  end

end
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your subspecs cannot depend on the parent spec, but can depend on other subspecs. You probably want to create some sort of "Core" subspec, then have SubPod 1 and 2 depend on that.

Comment: Many thanks MishieMoo, I followed your suggestion of using sub specs. Unfortunately the pod spec lint command was taking over 10 minutes to validate and I decided to review the .podspec configuration. I have now decided that there’s no benefit in retaining the the directory structure within the POD, it is retained in the bitbucket repository.